# What is equivalent of Facebook pixel in GTM for server side tagging?

Tags: google-tag-manager, facebook-pixel

With recently introduced feature of GTM, server side tagging and it's known benefits, I want to move my Facebook pixel browser code on server. So I am looking for equivalent of Facebook pixel for server side tagging.

The closest thing I found is Facebook Conversion api but not exactly same.

Would like to hear other views on how they are achieving this

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a lot to learn and work to do this.

1. You need to understand the Facebook pixel hit's payload. Something like `https://www.facebook.com/tr/?id={{pixelId}}&ev={{event}}&dl={{Document location}}...`
2. Assemble the payload and send it to your Server Side GTM.
3. Create `Client` in the Server Side GTM to receive the hit.
4. Create `Tag` to dispatch the hit to Facebook.

The Server-Side GTM is not supported the 3rd party cookie and it means that the Facebook will not recognize the user you send from Server-Side GTM.
Facebook report will only show the conversion or event amount.
Can't use this for remarketing or attribution.

Comment: That's, not true. You can use cookie and remarking and all other staff when using  onversions-api check this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/conversions-api/

Comment: Maybe it's my ignorance. Just wondering how to get the facebook 3rd party cookie and send it to Server-side GTM container.

Comment: If you use server side tracking you don't need to use any Facebook SDK and 3rd party cookies. To identify user with Facebook conversion (click on ad) you need to get fbc and fbp parameters. How to generate them you can read in this document https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/conversions-api/parameters/fbp-and-fbc

Answer (score 0):

There are was no official Tag from Facebook for GTM Server Side. That's why I created my own https://github.com/gtm-server/facebook-tag

The tag sends the event data from the Universal Analytics/GA4 client to Facebook.

It developed exactly like an easy replacement for Facebook WEB pixel.

Comment: If you use this or the conversions API in general in lieu of the Facebook Pixel, will you be giving up [Advanced Matching](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/611774685654668)? Seems like you get performance and control, but if the data collected is different, it would be important for marketing teams to track any differences in audiences and tracking too.